# How to copy a database table column to another database

Tags: mysql, database, sequelpro

I am using Sequel Pro to copy data from an old database to a new one. I know you can select rows and copy them as an `SQL INSERT` etc. But the layout for my new data base has changed and I no longer want to copy all the data in the rows. I just need to be able to get specific columns. I know I could copy all the rows then cut the parts I don't want out, but that would be a lot of work as I'm working with a lot of data. Surely there's something I can run to do this?

Here's what I want to be able to do. I have both the old database and the new one uploaded to my website so I can access them both through Sequel Pro. My old database is called old_db and the new one is called `wordpress`.

I need to be able to select the `wp_users` table inside old_db and select the following columns, `ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass` etc. and copy them into the `wp_users` table inside my new database `wordpress`.

Comment: Why not just something like `SELECT yourSpecificColumn ....` or did I fail to understand your request?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I would if I knew how haha. If you could either show me an example of how to do this or link me to the information that I need I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: _link me to the information..._ [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) might help you

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do this with the following in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO wordpress.wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) SELECT ID, user_login FROM old_db.wp_users;
```